# delay.h: No such file or directory

Tags: avr

I wrote a simple code in Atmel Studio 6.1 to blink a LED.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <delay.h>

int main(void)
{
...

return (0); 

}
```

The problem is when I compile the code I get the following error:

```
delay.h: No such file or directory
```

I don't think delay.h is not available because it is in this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native \3.4.2.1002     
\avr8-gnu-toolchain\avr\include\avr\delay.h
```

What's actually going on?

Comment: Is it in the same location as io.h because the paths you include are different

Comment: Yes, io.h is also there. So what does it have to do with delay.h?

Comment: So should it not be `<avr/delay.h>` ?

Comment: also I don't see delay.h in the dependencies folder, maybe that's why it doesn't recognize it? I couldn't add it to the folder though

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thank you so much for pointing it out! It now happily works:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to solve your problem.

```
#include <util/delay.h>
```

Comment: #include <util/delay.h>